# What if I use 4 pin XLR instead of the 3 pin one?

Tags: connector, wireless, cables, pins

I'm a guitar player and my knowledge about connectors and stuff is very disappointing. 
I use a wireless device to play live and the cable I use to plug the guitar is a Jack to mini XLR (3 pin) cable, such as this:

[image: ![]

However, the quality of this cable is dreadfull as it is a lowcost cable. So I was searching for a better one and saw this one:

[image]

The problem is this XLR connector is a 4 pinned one.

So here goes my question:

Will it make any difference if I plug a 4 pinned XLR instead of a 3 pinned one, as the extra pin will not be plugged anywhere?

What I think is, since the jack is 2 pinned the 3rd and 4th pin would not be used anyway.

I hope everything is clear to you, thanks!

---

Thanks, after reading all your quick responses I've decided that the way to go would be to make my own cable out of connectors and wire.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. As your post stands we would have to look up two links to figure out what you are talking about. Not many of us will bother. You should add the images to your post to make it easy for the readers. This way the Q & As will remain relevant even if the links die.

Comment: My guess would be that it would just sound the same like the old cable...

Comment: It could be that the cable is so bad that the signal drops out or something. But I am reminded of a Telecaster forum where some members were so obsessed with audiophoolery, particularly surrounding the notion that cavity and cable shielding increases the capacitance and thus changes the resonant frequency of the guitar, that one member took it upon himself to write a 2000 word tutorial on how to find the tone knob, and how and why to use it.

Comment: Shure Microphones 4 pin dosen't work in 3 pin. If you change the plug, it also dosen't work.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the pinouts from [Switchcraft's web site](http://www.switchcraft.com/Drawings/TA_FX_SERIES_CD.PDF):

[image]

It doesn't look like the 4 pin plug will fit in a 3 pin socket to me. In fact, ranges of connectors like these are often designed specifically to make it impossible to plug the wrong plug and socket combinations together.

Comment: Yes, pin 1 and pin 3 seem to be positioned differently. So here's my advice to the OP: Take 5 minutes extra or pay 1 dollar more, and get a decent cable with the proper connector. Problem solved. 3 pin XLR cables aren't exactly rare.

Comment: XLR cables certainly aren't rare, but mini XLR cables are a bit harder to find.

Comment: True, but still not _that_ hard. https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=shop&q=jack+to+mini+xlr